What is the maximum supported RAM for the Acer Nitro 5 AN515-57?
What is the maximum supported RAM for Acer's Nitro 5 AN515-57? I've been told two conflicting numbers, either 64GB or 32GB, but I need to be certain.
Additionally, for the RAM sticks I buy, what MHz speed would be best to match the Core i5 2688mhz processor?

www.crucial.com will tell you.

According to the Acer store, it supports up to 32 GB over two memory slots. Check under the "Specifications" tab for more information.
